# bitwise_and how does it works?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, bitwise-and

I am trying to understand the how the function cv2.bitwise_and(src1,src2,mask) works. So I tried this code:

```
src1=np.array([1, 2, 3])

src1=np.uint8(src1)

mask=np.array([1,1,4])

mask=np.uint8(mask)

_, mask_bin= cv2.threshold(mask,3,1,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

res=cv2.bitwise_and(src1,src1,mask_bin)
```

From documentation I understand that the and operation will done if `mask[I]` not equal zero. But I didn't get that why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got the right understanding, you just called `bitwise_and` wrong. Use

```
res=cv2.bitwise_and(src1,src1,mask=mask_bin)
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and), `bitwise_and`'s only mandatory arguments are the two source images.

> cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2[, dst[, mask]]) → dst

Giving it a third argument (`mask_bin`) with no other information, it will consider it by default as its first optionnal argument, which is `dst`, an output array. You need to tell him you want `mask_bin` to be the mask optionnal argument.

Replacing this line gives `[0,0,3]`, which is what you should expect.

Comment: That was spot on!!

Comment: @MohammedAwney Since it solved your problem, you might want to accept this answer.